# Which story referenced the parable of Custer’s last stand?

Tags: identification-request

I’m trying to figure out where I first came across this “parable of Little Big Horn”. I think (but I’m not 100% sure) that this was a story told by a narrator at the beginning of a novel.

The gist of the parable was that Custer had murdered a soldier and engineered the massacre to cover up the death. It’s possible that there was an implication that Custer had had a relationship with the soldier he killed, but I’m not certain.

I read this about 10 years ago, though the book I read it in was almost definitely not newly published at the time. I think it was in a novel, but it may possibly have been a collection of short stories.

I can’t remember much else about the novel, this short section really stood apart from it in my memory. I have a feeling that the genre was something like magical realism. Possibly Gabriel Garcia Marquez or David Mitchell, I’m not 100% sure about that though. I think it was a high brow-ish book; the kind of book that you might find on a short list for the Booker Prize… I read it in English.

Has anyone heard of this story? And if so, where?

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! When did you read this? What was the rest of the novel like? Could you provide any other details about the parable? See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) for more information which could help narrow this down into something more easily answerable.

Comment: @bobble thanks for the suggestion and link to the wiki! I’ve gone back and added as much detail as I can, even where I’m not sure. My memory is really hazy on this one

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail. This is probably unnecessary, but just to confirm - you read this in English, yes?

Comment: Yes, I did. I’d meant to include that. Question updated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds a lot like *The Sign of the Broken Sword*, a story in the Father Brown series by G.K. Chesterton. It's a short story in a collection.

It wasn't Custer, it was a fictional British soldier.

[You can read it here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Innocence_of_Father_Brown/The_Sign_of_the_Broken_Sword).

Here's a quote:

> Flambeau seemed suddenly galvanised into existence. "You mean," he cried hoarsely, "that General St. Clare hated Murray, and murdered him on the field of battle because——"
>
> "You are still full of good and pure thoughts," said the other. "It was worse than that."
>
> "Well," said the large man, "my stock of evil imagination is used up."
>
> The priest seemed really doubtful where to begin, and at last he said again:
>
> "Where would a wise man hide a leaf? In the forest."
>
> The other did not answer.
>
> "If there were no forest, he would make a forest. And if he wished to hide a dead leaf, he would make a dead forest."
>
> There was still no reply, and the priest added still more mildly and quietly:
>
> "And if a man had to hide a dead body, he would make a field of dead bodies to hide it in."
> ...
>
> "But another man had talked to Espado the Vulture as well as he. Somehow the dark, grim young major from Ulster had guessed the hideous truth; and when they walked slowly together down that road towards the bridge Murray was telling the general that he must resign instantly, or be court-martialled and shot. The general temporised with him till they came to the fringe of tropic trees by the bridge; and there by the singing river and the sunlit palms (for I can see the picture) the general drew his sabre and plunged it through the body of the major." ...  He saw that men must find the unaccountable corpse; must extract the unaccountable sword-point; must notice the unaccountable broken sword—or absence of sword. He had killed, but not silenced. But his imperious intellect rose against the facer; there was one way yet. He could make the corpse less unaccountable. He could create a hill of corpses to cover this one. In twenty minutes eight hundred English soldiers were marching down to their death."

Comment: Ah, that's it, exactly! I'm very impressed you managed to get it even with all the red herrings I'd misremembered. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the central concept of starting a battle to hide a murder was close enough on its own.